# Using BIND DLZ through LDAPS or LDAPI

Tags: linux, ssl, bind, openldap

Before hardening this server, I had the bind DNS server working flawlessly and storing the DNS database within the OpenLDAP directory through LDAP:// using the following configuration under named.conf:

```
dlz "ldap zone" {
database "ldap 2
v3 simple {uid=bind/test-machine.example.com,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com} {secret} localhost ldap:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com???objectclass=dlzZone
ldap:///dlzHostName=\$record\$,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldap:///dlzHostName=@,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,=dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzData,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(dlzType=soa))
ldap:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzHostname,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectClass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldap:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(&(objectclass=dlzXFR)(dlzIPAddr=\$client\$))";
};
```

Due to some security requirements, I had to configure the OpenLDAP directory to enforce SSL except for the LDAPI:/// socket:

```
- olcSecurity: ssf=256
- olcLocalSSF: 256
- olcRequires: authc
- olcDisallow: bind_anon
- olcTLSVerifyClient: try
```

Since I could not find any information about using Bind-DLZ through LDAPS or LDAPI (Both servers are on the same machine, so there would not be a problem to use the local socket), I tried to run the following configuration:

```
dlz "ldap zone" {
database "ldap 2
v3 simple {uid=bind/test-machine.example.com,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com} {secret} localhost ldaps:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com???objectclass=dlzZone
ldaps:///dlzHostName=\$record\$,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldaps:///dlzHostName=@,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,=dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzData,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(dlzType=soa))
ldaps:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzHostname,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectClass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldaps:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(&(objectclass=dlzXFR)(dlzIPAddr=\$client\$))";
};
```

I could not start the service. The logs showed up:

```
allow zone transfer query must not specify a port
SDLZ driver failed to load
DLZ driver failed to load
Loading configuration: failure
Exiting (due to fatal error)
Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
```

So I tried to use the following configuration with the same result:

```
dlz "ldap zone" {
database "ldap 2
v3 simple {uid=bind/test-machine.example.com,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com} {secret} localhost ldapi:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com???objectclass=dlzZone
ldapi:///dlzHostName=\$record\$,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldapi:///dlzHostName=@,dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,=dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzData,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectclass=dlzAbstractRecord)(dlzType=soa))
ldapi:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com?dlzTTL,dlzType,dlzHostname,dlzPreference,dlzData,dlzIpAddr,dlzPrimaryNS,dlzAdminEmail,dlzSerial,dlzRefresh,dlzRetry,dlzExpire,dlzMinimum?sub?(&(objectClass=dlzAbstractRecord)(!(dlzType=soa)))
ldapi:///dlzZoneName=\$zone\$,ou=dns,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(&(objectclass=dlzXFR)(dlzIPAddr=\$client\$))";
};
```

Could not start named.service:

```
allow zone transfer query must not specify a port
SDLZ driver failed to load
DLZ driver failed to load
Loading configuration: failure
Exiting (due to fatal error)
Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
```

I post my issue on the bind-users mail list and one of the users told me that it should work since it uses the openldap libraries as a ldapsearch query.

I verified that the binary was retrieving the correct libraries:

```
 # ldd /usr/sbin/named 

[...]
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fc6d482d000) 
[...]
```

And the same for all the libraries like libssl, libgssapi_krb5... there are not any "not found" libraries. I suppose that in case of any problem with libldap librarie, named could not connect to slapd without the olcSecurity SSF options either.

The Bind DLZ used is the one compiled with the BIND 9.16.6 (Stable Release) from the SUSE 15 SP2 repository.

**EDIT:**
I'm checking the source code of bind dlz since we need to use ldaps instead of ldap.
I found this on the source code of BIND DLZ:

```
If (ldap_url->lud_port != 389) {
    db->log(ISC_LOG_ERROR,"%s query must not specify a port", msg);
    result = ISC_R_FAILURE;
    goto cleanup;
}
```

I understand that this error control only involves the query and not the connection.

Checking the connection parameter function:

```
dbc->dbconn = ldap_init(dbi->hosts,LDAP_PORT);
if (dbc->dbconn == NULL) {
    return (ISC_R_NOMEMORY) ;
}
```

This uses a deprecated openldap function and sends a constant as port (LDAP_PORT)
If we check the ldap.h where ldap_init is defined:

```
#define LDAP_PORT       389     /* ldap:///     default LDAP port */
#define LDAPS_PORT      636     /* ldaps:///    default LDAP over TLS port */
```

Some help would be very appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Regards.